# concurrency in delayed_jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have ROR application and 1 delay_job process ran using rake job:work.
ROR application add Job in multiple queue.

Lets say we have queue 1 and queue 2.
My Question is task in queue 1 and task in queue 2 will be executed concurrently?

Currently in my application after running rake job:work process only 1 thread is spawn which executes queue1 task and then queue2 task.
If i have to execute in parallel, i have to run two rake task of job:work.

Is it correct behavior or it can be run concurrently in 1 rake task of job:work.
And what is worker in Delay Job. Is delay Job interchangeably used with worker

Thanks
Priyanka

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, one worker cannot run two jobs concurrently, you need more than one process running for that.

In the example you are describing, you are starting a worker that is running in the foreground (`rake job:work`), but what you could do instead, is to start them as background workers, by running `bin/delayed_job` instead (`script/delayed_job` for earlier versions). That command has multiple options that you can use to specify how you want delayed_job to function.

One of the options is `-n` or `--number_of_workers=workers`. That means you can start two workers by running the following command:

```
bundle exec bin/delayed_job --number_of_workers=2 start
```

It is also possible to dedicate certain workers to only run jobs from a specific queue, or only high priority jobs.

Comment: Thanks.   Please confirm my understanding . As per my understanding number of workers mean number of delay jobs processes.Calling rake job:work or bundle exec bin/delayed_job is same thing.I can either call 2 rake job:work or pass worker option in bundle exec . And in my scenario we have to run two processes for two queues to achieve concurrency or parallelism.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Workers are what we call the processes. Bear in mind though that when calling rake job:work, you cannot close the terminal because it will terminate the process. That's why you should use the script bin/delayed_job. And I don't think you need to think about the concept of different queues. It sounds like having one queue that both processes take from, is what you need.

Comment: So there is only one purpose of Named Queue ,i.e  it can be ran by different Delay Job process ? And logically queues should be less than or equal to no of delay jobs?

Comment: No, you can have more queues then processes if you want. One process can be told to pick jobs from multiple different queues by using the command line option `--queues=...`. But you have to think of why you would need different queues. One reason would be if a type of job uses an external OS library. Then you need to make sure that you start a worker process from a server that has that library installed. But most other jobs can be handled by a worker process on a lightweight server to be more efficient.

Comment: Yes you are right we can have more queues than number of delay Jobs. But I meant I don't think we should do that or I don't understand what will be that use case where we would want more queues than number of delay jobs.  Also I didn't understand your external OS library example. My understanding is that we can create queues for different task like sending mail or downloading file which we knew in advance and which we want to run asynchronously as background process.

Comment: My point is that even if you have two types of jobs, (say download files and sending email), you can have both those jobs in the same queue and then two or more processes working off that one queue in parallel. So you don't have to create two separate queues if you don't need to. But say for example that some of the files take a long time to download, effectively locking up the process while downloading, and at the same time you require emails to be send out immediately without delay. In that case you can dedicate one of the processes to only work from the email queue.

Comment: And the scenario for having more queues than workers could be for scaling reasons. You can have multiple queues for different purposes, preparing for future increases in load/traffic. In the beginning, you can have one process working all queues, but then as load increases and you need to balance, you can start up more workers dedicated to only some queues. But that's just of the top of my head. Business logic can sometimes be difficult to predict.